# Is there a definitive reference for both the video tag and the JS API used to communicate with it? (html5)

Tags: video, html

Is there a definitive reference for both the video tag and the JS API used to communicate with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's not definitive yet, because the specification is still in draft. But the HTML5 specification is and will be the definitive reference. It also describes the standard scripting interfaces.

- [The section on the video element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/video.html#video)
- Linked from there is the reference for the [HTMLMediaElement interface](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/video.html#htmlmediaelement), which is shared with `audio`.